# adb connect connection refused

Tags: android, ubuntu, adb, linux-mint

I am trying to develop an app with Flutter. I used to connect my Android phone "Samsun J7" via a USB cord to my Linux box and I was able to see it listed as a mounted device in my file manager. VSCode would be able to list the device so I can choose it to build the app on it. For some reason, could be updating my Linux Mint 19 machine to the latest Kernel available, I can't see the phone mounted anymore. I have tried all solutions I could find here but to no avail. I even tried other devices of different brands but non would work. `adb` is installed, developer option is enabled, `USB Debugging` is on (I used to use the phone before, and I enabled it for other devices, too) but none would be seen by my machine. When I try `adb devices` the device is not listed (the list is empty) and when I tried `adb connect <IP>:5555` (5555 is the port recommended by most solutions) I get connection refused. I got the IP from the "About the phone" menu which is something like `192.168.xx.xxx`. killing and starting the `adb server` did not help. I don't know what else should I do.
My Linux distro is: Linux Mint 19 LTS, Kernel: 4.15.0-153. Android on phone is ver. 9 and kernel version is 4.9.112. Security patch level: May 1, 2021.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, wireless debugging is only supported in [Android 11+](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb). Therefore, any adb command you run relating to it such as `adb connect` will fail. Consequently, restarting the server will not help either. You will have to use adb via USB.

According to the [Android Developer Docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device), there are a few conditions the user must meet in order to connect to a device via USB.
First, you must be in the `plugdev` group. Use the `id` command to ensure you are. If not, run `sudo usermod -aG plugdev $LOGNAME`.
Next, you must have udev rules installed that cover the device. These come installed by default in the `android-sdk-platform-tools-common` package. Use `apt-get install android-sdk-platform-tools-common` to install them, and run adb out of that directory.

Finally, logout and log back in to ensure the changes have taken place.

Once you have done all this, connect your device via USB and run `adb devices` again.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have already done these steps. As I explained above the two devices I used before connected well and were used for building my app. They both worked fine. After upgrading the kernel (maybe) they are not detected anymore.

Comment: Are you sure? I connected many different devices that runs on Android 8/9 etc over wifi and didnt have any trouble

Comment: You're right. Wifi debugging is possible in Android versions lower than 10. But I believe in order to do it, you would have to connect the device via USB first. I did not mention this because OP said they could not connect via USB.

Comment: > _you would have to connect the device via USB first_
This is also untrue. I have connected to a device running Android 8 via adb over network without previously connecting to it over USB.